# Laravel 9 - Seeder | TypeError array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array, int given

Tags: php, typeerror, laravel-9, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I have two tables named Order and OrderItem. While creating data in the Order table, I am trying to enter data into the OrderItem table at the same time. The codes are as follows;

**OrderSeeder.php**

```
public function run()
{
    Order::factory()->count(30)->create()
        ->each(function (Order $order) {
            Order::factory( OrderItem::class, random_int(1, 5))->create([
               'order_id' => $order->id,
            ]);
        });
}
```

**OrderFactory.php**

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => $this->faker->name(),
        'last_name' => $this->faker->lastName(),
        'email' => $this->faker->email(),

    ];
}
```

**OrderItemFactory.php**

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'product_title' => $this->faker->text(30),
        'price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(10.100),
        'quantity' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 5),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please post full the full error message in the body of the question. Currently, it's difficult to notice what the question is and also may lack detail that would be helpful in determining the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Creating the same error message is difficult right now. I'll take your warning into account in my next question.

Comment: @Mustafa Bayram mark as correct or close it.

Comment: When i try
** I get the message "You can accept your own answer in 2 days **. I'll try again when the time is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I updated the page like this, the problem was solved.

**OrderSeeder.php**

```
public function run()
{
    Order::factory(10)
        ->create()
        ->each(function ($order) {
            OrderItem::factory(random_int(1,3))
                ->create([
                    'order_id' => $order->id,
                ]);
        });
}
```

You can use it as a [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#has-many-relationships) when you encounter a similar error..

Comment: Most of your Q&A is in English, and as this is an English language site, we request you to post wholly in English, can you please update your answer so that any and all readers find this accessible to them :)